# Cannot modify a model field on save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm a beginner with Django, and first time askig :)

I'm following a simple tutorial on generating a slug for a string (let's say a slug for a blog post generated from its title).
Perhaps I'm following an outdated guide, perhaps I'm missing a basic thing, I have no idea.

- Django 2.0
- Python 3.6

I am trying to do a very simple task of slugifying a simple string, so:

1. User enters a string in a simple form
2. When hitting 'save', the title goes through slugify and creates the
   slug
3. Save.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models    

class Testmodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView    

class TestCreate(CreateView):
    model = Testmodel
    fields = '__all__'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Testmodel

class TestCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Testmodel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Up until here everythig works, if I enter the slug manualy. In order to do it automaticaly, I have tried:

1. Overriding the `save()` method withing my ModelForm class.
2. Overriding the `form_valid()` method within the CreateView
3. Overriding the `save()` method within the model itself.
4. Tried to connect a pre_save signal to the model.

In all of these 4 tries, I had the same results:

- When generating the form with the slug field, I couldn't do anything because it was required.
- When generating the form without the slug field, nothing happens when I hit save.

The only way I have found to dodge this issue is to set the slug field to `blank = True` as well. I am not sure how secure it is, though?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You've written a wonderfuly constructed question (Cheers!)

> When generating the form with the slug field, I couldn't do anything because it was required.

Okay so first we exlcude the slug because we want it to be autogenerated.

You can do this by

```
class TestCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Testmodel
        exclude = ['slug']
```

Now you'll get a form without the slug field.

> When generating the form without the slug field, nothing happens when I hit save.

Now we override the `save()` function of the model itself since slug is a part of the model.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But this will generate the slug everytime the model is saved.

We can go a step further and make sure the slug is set only if the model is 'created' and not every time it is 'updated'

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Well, first of all this worked perfectly. Thank you very much!
I just want to be sure I got it - what you've suggested is to use `exclude` on the Meta class of the ModelForm, but when CreateView I have to state the fields also (under `fields = ['title', 'additional_field']` - I couldn't find an `exclude` option. Does this mean that if I have a form with 20 fields I have to manualy define which fields to "exclude"?

Comment: @Pumi Happy to help! You're welcome :)
Let me know if you get stuck somewhere again ^_^